# Why does FTOC apply here, to find the derivative of $\int_{\sin(x)}^{\pi} \frac{t}{\cos(t)} dt$

Tags: calculus

If we let $F(x) = \int_{\sin x}^{\pi} \frac{t}{\cos t} dt$, and $f(t) = \frac{t}{\cos t}$

My question is why does FTOC apply here? Here is why I think it does not, please correct me if I am wrong:

For F'(x) to be calculated using FTOC, a condition to use FTOC is that f(t) must be continuous over the interval where we are integrating the function. However, since the lower bound on F(x) is sin(x), which ranges from [-1, 1], we know that the interval would always include the point $\frac{\pi}{2}$. At $f(\frac{\pi}{2})$, the function is not defined (it is a vertical asymptote) as $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})$ is 0. So how does FTOC apply here?

Comment: With $F(x)$ as defined in the question, there is no problem whatsoever as the integrand is continuous on $[-1,1]$. However, the integral in the title does not converge, for any value of $x$.

Comment: And now you have the same divergent integral in both the title and the question. Obviously, you **can't** apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to a divergent integral.

Answer (score 2):

$ f $ is defined for $ t $ such that

$$t\ne \frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$$
or
$$t\in \Bbb R -\{...,-1.57,157,....\}$$

For $ x\in \Bbb R $, we have

$$[0,\sin(x)]\subset [-1,1]$$

and

$$\frac{\pi}{2}\approx 1.57\notin [-1,1]$$

$ f $ is continuous at $ [-1,1] $ and consequently at $ [0,\sin(x)]$

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake when writing out the limits of F(x) in the comments.